# Select all of the objects (lines) of one shapefile in a larger shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select

So I have a small shapefile that was merged with a bunch of other shapefiles into a larger shapefile.

The small shapefile has around 15,000 objects each with an ID. I want to make that selection in the large shapefile.

Is that possible in an easy way? I'm new to ArcMap. I forgot to edit some of the attributes before merging and want to find a way to select the individual sets so I can attribute them appropriately.

Edit: From what I remember (data is loaded at my work desk), the IDs were unique. There's no overlap of IDs in the merged shapefile if that's what you mean. The IDs are distinct to the individual sets that they came from.

Comment: Do you have a unique feature ID (not FID) in both datasets?

Comment: Yeah, from what I remember (data is loaded at my work desk), the IDs were unique. There's no overlap of IDs in the merged shapefile if that's what you mean. The IDs are distinct to the individual sets that they came from.

Comment: FIDs in shapefiles are 0 based, unique, contiguous and ascending.. they change **frequently during editing** and cannot be relied on to form a Join... if there's a different field that matches with the larger shapefile you might be able to use that otherwise you're stuck with *select by location, completely within, buffer of a small value* which may not get all or include extras..

Comment: Thanks! I heard about Join but had a big misunderstanding of what it was used for from the looks of it. I'll look into those options.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer your question to need to mine the comments for critical information. You should also make certain that the exact software in use is within the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the small feature class features are all included in the large feature class, you can use 'select by location' for this task.

Open 'Select by location'.  Tick the large feature class as the target layer.  Select the small feature class as the source layer.  Set the relationship to 'are identical to the source layer feature'.

This will select all the features from your large feature class that came from the small feature class.  Double check the selection count matches the number of records in the small feature class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Select by Location** property to select the features from the merged dataset based on the original dataset. This way the original features will be highlighted and you can make changes.

More information about **Select by Location** can be found here.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm